# JQL - use variable in query

Tags: python, jira, jql

I'm trying to use variable in JQL

```
client = 'Newbie'
query = "Managed Services On-boarding " + client
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('jql', 'project="Managed Services" AND summary~'"'+query+'"' AND issuetype="Task" AND status!="DONE"'),
)
```

above gives me zero result

but if i hard code query i got results

```
params = (
    ('jql', 'project="Managed Services" AND summary~"Managed Services On-boarding Newbie" AND issuetype="Task" AND status!="DONE"'),
)
```

is there any way to use variable in JQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake with your quotation marks around your query variable.
Try it like that:

```
client = 'Newbie'
query = "Managed Services On-boarding " + client
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('jql', 'project="Managed Services" AND summary~"'+query+'" AND issuetype="Task" AND status!="DONE"'),
)
```